# ¿como obtener el elemento mas grande de cada fila con numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

intento obtener una lista de los indice de los elementos de mayor tamaño de cada fila

```
a = np.arange(16).reshape((4, 4))
print(a)
print(np.amax(a, axis=1))
print(np.where(a == np.amax(a, axis=1)))
```

este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me da el mas grande de la matriz la funcion **where**.

en este caso la lista resultado que quiero obtener seria:

`[3, 3, 3, 3]`

que es en la columna que esta el elemento

Answer (score 3, accepted):

numpy implementa la funcion [`argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) que retorna el indice más pequeño del elemento más grande de una fila, columna o de todo el array, como tu quieres el elemento mas grande de una fila debes usar axis=1, por ejemplo:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(20, size=16).reshape((4, 4))
print(a)

print(np.argmax(a, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
[[10 15  2  3]
 [ 9  0 10 19]
 [ 3 18 17 18]
 [ 5 15  4  8]]
[1 3 1 1]
```

Comment: gracias funciona